# Is it possible to make screenshots remotely on iOS devices managed by MDM?

Tags: ios, mdm

Subj.

I know it's possible to track location, installed apps and restrict some basic features on iOS devices managed by MDM.
What about making screenshots? Does MDM allow that?

Not looking into jailbreak-related solutions.